# CSS | How to create selector for particular component instance?

Tags: css, oracle, css-selectors, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

### Lets say I have two instances of one component. What I want is my component to have a unique appearance but not change all other instances of that component. So I need to create selector for particular component instance.

Let’s say my page has a structure like this:

```
<af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl1" layout="scroll" styleClass="SpecialMarker">
  <af:inputText id="it1" label="Name"/>
</af:panelGroupLayout>
```

To style that inputText specially in this container, I would need to create skinning definitions like this. This will effect only this particular instance of the component:

```
.SpecialMarker af|inputText {background-color:pink}
.SpecialMarker af|inputText::access-key {color: aqua;}
.SpecialMarker af|inputText::content {background-color:red}
.SpecialMarker af|inputText::label {font-weight: bold}
```

But that doesn`t work for me. My goal is to resize af:train (ADF) component depending on screen width.

P.S.I use ADF on Jdeveloper 11.1.1.7.

Answer (score 0):

For the example you give, you should do

```css
af|panelGroupLayout.SpecialMarker af|inputText {background-color:pink}
af|panelGroupLayout.SpecialMarker af|inputText::access-key {color: aqua;}
af|panelGroupLayout.SpecialMarker af|inputText::content {background-color:red}
af|panelGroupLayout.SpecialMarker af|inputText::label {font-weight: bold}
```

Note that you might need to add !important to some statements to override the default CSS.

Comment: Is there any other option instead of using !important to override the default CSS?

Comment: UPDATE: adding !important doesn`t resolve my issue. Still I can`t override default CSS that way.

Comment: I guess adding stylclasses for the af:inputText's isn't an option?